# NSDictionary sort algorithm custom

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary, quicksort, mergesort

I am using `NSDictionary` and method for sorting `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector`. It is possible replace this sorting algorithm by `quicksort` or `mergesort`?

Thank you

Comment: One question: *Why*?

Comment: @luk2302 I dont know which algorithm is using I need that sort will have < O(N^2).

Comment: That is pretty low requirement, i am 99.995% sure that it will always be < O(N^2), even in the worst case.

Comment: Do you really think Apple would be using a sort algorithm that runs in O (N^2)? How many developers use MacOS X and iOS? How many complaints do you think Apple would get? To tell it bluntly, _you_ cannot replace the sort with something faster.

Comment: @gnasher729 I know but I want to try if it is possible.

Comment: Firstly it is not possible, secondly if you *could* replace it, you would to fail to replace it with something faster, since there is nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously call [myDictionary allKeys] and sort that array using any method that you like. This is guaranteed to be slower than what Apple does.

Comment: I know that it will be slower but, do you have any example when I want sort it with quicksort and by value?